# GC Not Cleaning Up (was: Tempfile Not Deleting Automatically, Ruby)

Tags: ruby, configuration

Ruby tempfile instances automatically delete their corresponding file when the references are released. However, I have one machine on which this is not the case. The code is

```
irb> require 'tempfile'
=> true
irb> t = Tempfile.new('test32')
=> #<File:/tmp/test32.27778.0>
irb> exit
```

on all of my test machines, this results in test32 getting deleted, except one. I have tried to delete a file using `File.delete` and unfortunately that works fine. Is there some ruby config I'm missing?

Ruby version is

```
ruby 1.8.6 (2009-06-08 patchlevel 369) [i686-linux].
```

**Edit:** Some additional information that has come to light in the conversation with DigitalRoss: If I explicitly release the Tempfile reference (t = nil), then the Tempfile gets cleaned up. **Is is possible that the GC has been patched or altered in some way to need that?**

Here's some code that works on the "good" machines but on the "bad" machine it fails

```
include ObjectSpace
t = "blah"
define_finalizer(t, proc {|id| print "yes finalized id=#{id}", "\n" })
```

On the bad machine, the "yes finalized" only prints if I explicitly set t to nil.

Comment: Try this: >> $DEBUG=true >> exit, and see if it prints "removing..." or in some other way acts differently between your systems...

Comment: good idea, but nothing there on either the good nor the bad systems.

Comment: Wait a second, you mean it does print "removing..."? If so, then the next step is to go to /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/tempfile.rb and add some debugging code after the "print "removing..." if $DEBUG" code. and in particular right before and after the File.unlink. If $DEBUG does NOT print "removing" then report that here, please.

Comment: (Or use the debugger in a similar fashion...)

Comment: Aha! Sorry about that, I get it now. Yes, $DEBUG does make the "good" system print the removing lines and the bad system does not output anything... I have inspected the tempfile.rb and it does have this line "print "removing ", path, "..." if $DEBUG" as expected...

Comment: Hmm, it's a bit prospective, but I can't format comments so I guess I will open an answer and edit it until we nuke this... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, continuing the question's comment thread...

Ruby, or really, `Tempfile`, uses the garbage collector to manage finalizers. (I presume it works this way rather than via Kernel::at_exit in order to delete the file earlier in a long-running ruby.) Anyway, something seems different about GC on one system. Let's try to pin it down. Try this, and see if clearing the only reference to the Tempfile instance and starting GC removes the file.

```
ross@deb:~$ irb
>> require 'tempfile'
=> true
>> $DEBUG=true
=> true
>> t=Tempfile.new('aaa')
=> #<File:/tmp/aaa20090905-21437-1d460as-0>
>> GC.start
=> nil
>> t=nil
=> nil
>> GC.start
removing /tmp/aaa20090905-21437-1d460as-0...done
=> nil
>> exit
ross@deb:~$
```

Comment: Okay, perfect, thanks, I'll be checking this shortly and reporting back. In the meantime, let's leave the absurd comments on the question: in a few years who knows what will be useful :)

Comment: Very interesting: on the machine where the file is not getting cleaned out, merely setting the t = nil and doing 'exit' causes the automatic removal to happen. Exit or GC.start, but if I don't set t to nil it doesn't get cleaned up. Ideas?

Comment: also: how can I tell if my GC has been patched?

Comment: I checked out the ruby 1.8 source with
svn co http://svn.ruby-lang.org/repos/ruby/branches/ruby_1_8
and found rb_gc_call_finalizer_at_exit in gc.c
Unfortunately, I can't reproduce your bug, so you may need to follow along and bash on gc.c yourself a bit.

Comment: Actually, it occurs to me that trying the latest 1.8 source (which is what you get with the above checkout) might win even without any debugging. At a minimum you would have a common baseline test.

Comment: Beginning to suspect that my colleague might've applied a patch to the GC like this one http://github.com/skaes/railsbench/tree/master... later on today or tomorrow I'll know. Thanks again for all of your help. This has been a great learning experience for me, too.

Comment: Heh, scan the filesystem for ruby source :-)

Comment: Colleague says that he compiled Ruby 1.8.6 from source himself (none was available for that OS), but that aside from that there's nothing weird about it... the plot thickens.

Answer (score 1):

In 1.8.7 there's an issue with the finalizer and the garbage collector, and it sounds likely from the description that you're running into the same thing in 1.8.6.

We managed to fix the problem in our rails app by monkey patching Tempfile.  Might work for you too.  Code: http://github.com/jwinky/ruby_tempfile_ioerror